# What is the powershell command to know whether the string contains a character which is other than the letters a-z, A-Z, 0-9,_,.,-?

Tags: regex, powershell, conditional-statements

What is the powershell command to know whether the string '/DSA_Global_UNIX/Library/Global/UNIX/Server Uptime Report/Server uptime  and Patch Compliance report' contains a character which is other than the letters a-z, A-Z, 0-9,_,.,- ?

Answer (score 1):

### Code

```
$str -match '[^\w.-]'
```

#### Usage

```
$str = "/DSA_Global_UNIX/Library/Global/UNIX/Server Uptime Report/Server uptime and Patch Compliance report"
$str -match '[^\w.-]'
```

---

### Results

For your string, it will return `true` because it contains `/` and  (space).

A string with only characters from the set `[\w.-]` will return false, for example:

```
DSA_Global_UnixLibraryGlobalUNIXServerUptimeReportServeruptimeandPathCompliancereport
```

Comment: Escape your period or it's a wildcard.

Comment: How sure are you? @TheIncorrigible1 a dot inside a set is not a wildcard. I think the incorrigible has just been corrected ;)

Comment: *grumble grumble* inconsistent regex rules

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 better yet, try using `\b` inside `[\b]` and outside a set `\b`, tell me what that gives you haha